# JSON.stringify.replace for updating Mail Merge code that uses Gmail draft as template

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a mail merge that picks the template from Gmail draft and then replaces all the {{columnName}} with respective column values from google sheet. Each mail is identified by a unique ID, say Employee ID.

Everything works great so far.

Now, I am trying to modify the following portion of the code so that I can update the values for two URLs from the Javascript instead of from the google sheet. The URLs are unique for each Employee ID, so have to be dynamically generated when each email is sent.

e.g. {{Accept}} will be replaced by accept_url  and {{Reject}} will be replaced by reject_url

Or I can use different symbols instead of curly brackets for the two URL variables. But how do I modify the following code for updating these URL variables dynamically?

```
function fillInTemplateFromObject_(template, data) {
    
        let template_string = JSON.stringify(template);
      
         // token replacement
        template_string = template_string.replace(/{{[^{}]+}}/g, key => {  
          return escapeData_(data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")] || "");
        });
      
        return  JSON.parse(template_string);
      }
    
    
      function escapeData_(str) {
        return str
          .replace(/[\\]/g, '\\\\')
          .replace(/[\"]/g, '\\\"')
          .replace(/[\/]/g, '\\/')
          .replace(/[\b]/g, '\\b')
          .replace(/[\f]/g, '\\f')
          .replace(/[\n]/g, '\\n')
          .replace(/[\r]/g, '\\r')
          .replace(/[\t]/g, '\\t');
      };
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample values of `template` and `data`?

Comment: I am modifying the code mentioned here https://developers.google.com/workspace/solutions/mail-merge

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Actually the issue was not resolved. I want to modify the code in this developers.google.com/workspace/solutions/mail-merge so that I can add a custom approve link in the mail merge.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I had thought your issue was resolved. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

No need for custom code. The mail merger already has this capability: When adding the link, you can add the template in the URL itself. For example, you can link some text to `https://example.com/{{id}}/` and it will correctly replace it with the ID.

Comment: It has to be the webApp URL with the id parameter. Can the above method still work?

Comment: Yes, but the spreadsheet value needs to be URI encoded (as component). If it's alphanumerical, you don't need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Accept URL updated in the code itself. The draft has  {{Accept}} tag which needs to be replaced with the webAppURL + Status+ ID where ID comes from the google sheet. Does this seem the best way to implement it?

```
  function fillInTemplateFromObject_(template, data) {
        // we have two templates one for plain text and the html body
        // stringifing the object means we can do a global replace
        
        var template_string = JSON.stringify(template);
        var url= WebAppUrl +'?status=true'+'&ID='+ID; //WebAppUrl  is global variable
        var htmlString;
        var ID =data[ID_COL];
         
         template_string=template_string.replace(/{{[^{}]+}}/g,function(key){
           
           if(key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "") =="Accept"){
             
              htmlString="<a href="+url +">Accept</a><br/>"
              return htmlString;
           }
            else{
                  
           return escapeData_(data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")] || "")
           }
         
         });     
      
        
        return  JSON.parse(template_string);   // convert back to object
    
      }
```